# react-onclickoutside don't work on iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I create the custom drop-down list based on the reactjs. I use react-onclickoutside for detecting of click in outside area and closing the my drop-down list. It work very good but not work for click in iframe area.

```
import onClickOutside from 'react-onclickoutside';

...

class DevicesGroupsFilter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            showGroups: false,  
        };
        this.renderGroups = this.renderGroups.bind(this);
        this.handleClickOutside = this.handleClickOutside.bind(this);
        this.handleOnClick = this.handleOnClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClickOutside(evt) {
        this.setState({showGroups: false});
    }

    handleOnClick(event) {
        this.setState({showGroups: !this.state.showGroups});
    }

    ...

    renderGroups() {
        if (this.state.showGroups) {
            return (<DevicesGroupsFilterList />)
        }
        return ""
    }

    render() {
        let className = "filter-wrap";
        if (this.state.showGroups) {
            className += " filter-dropped-down";
        }     

        return (
            <div className={className} id={this.props.elementId} >
                {this.renderGroups()}   
            </div>  
        )
    }
}


module.exports = {
    DevicesGroupsFilter: onClickOutside(DevicesGroupsFilter),
}
```

using (pass elementId through props of the react component):

```
ReactDOM.render(
        <DevicesGroupsFilter
                ...
                elementId={"my-groups-filter"}
                ...
        />, document.getElementById('place-groups-filter'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution based on [iframeTracker](https://github.com/vincepare/iframeTracker-jquery) jQuery Plugin for my problem.
1. Install the plugin

```
npm install jquery.iframetracker
```

2. Wrap the IFrame by div with class **iframetrack**

```
<div class="iframetrack" id="my-iframe-id">
    <iframe src="{{ src_url }}" seamless
    style="position: absolute; border: none; zoom:1.0; overflow-y:visible;"
    frameborder="0" width="100%" scrolling="auto" id="i-frame">
    {% trans "Your browser does not support the <iframe> tag" %}
    </iframe>
</div>
```

3. Add the callback handler for a blur event of the wrapped iframe

```
$('.iframetrack iframe').iframeTracker({
    blurCallback: function() 
    {
        // click when the list dropped down only.
        if ($('#my-groups-filter').hasClass('filter-dropped-down')) 
        {
            $('.filter-content').trigger('click');
        }
    }
});
```

When we release the mouse button (mouse up) in the wrapped iframe area the blurCallback execute. In this callback  we check the filter has or not the class 'filter-dropped-down'. If the filter has this class then we generate click for his closing.